# syntax error, unexpected end of file in ... on line 31

Tags: php, mysqli

I didn't have any code here on line 31 in this code so what do you think what's the problem here? :)

```
<?php

require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uname']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$pass'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
  echo "You are now logged in.";
  exit();
}

} else {

  $form = <<<EOT
  <form action="login.php" method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /></br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
  </form>
  EOT;
  echo $form;
}



?>
```

I think that all my brackets are fine :D

Comment: Remove the bracket `}`

Comment: Which one did you remove ? @AmarMuratović

Comment: in if statement and I also try last one

Comment: Is `EOT` indented? `That means especially that the identifier may not be indented` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php... `If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EOT token must be at column 1 in your editor.

```
<?php

require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['uname']);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

  $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$pass'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
  echo "You are now logged in.";
  exit();
}

} else {

  $form = <<<EOT
  <form action="login.php" method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /></br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
  </form>
EOT;
  echo $form;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks men this is correct answer :))

Answer (score 1):

The end of the `$form` string cannot be found, from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php:

> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line.

So you'll have to move `EOT;` to the very beginning of the line.

```
} else {

  $form = <<<EOT
  <form action="login.php" method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /></br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
  </form>
EOT;
  echo $form;
}
```